# What's a good E-Commerce Cart

Tags: templates, e-commerce, shopping-cart

What's a good Shopping Cart possibly free I know there oscommerce, xcart etc but what's a good one? And fairly easily to implement maintain and edit possibly merge with in my sites current theme.

If you mean technology as in web language which I hope you do than it's php. other then that I have no clue what you mean apache/mysql? amd?

Comment: Who's your payment services provider? Supporting their API is probably high on your list of needs...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- [Magento](http://www.magentocommerce.com/) (PHP)
- [Kona Kart](http://www.konakart.com/) (Java)
- [Big Commerce](http://www.bigcommerce.com/) (Haven't checked to see what this one is)

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://www.ror-e.com  it has a double entry accounting system, purchase orders, inventory management, shopping cart (with save for later and wish list) shipments, returns, coupons, customer credits.  check out the video http://www.ror-e.com/info/videos/1

All build with ruby on rails 3.